# Partition of p-groups and vector spaces

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra

I work on partition of $p$-groups such that $G/Z(G)$ is elementary abelian. As you know, we can think of such a factor group as a vector space. Therefore it connect to a partition of vector space. Partition of vector space has an important application in coding theory.

Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite $p$-group such that $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is an elementary abelian group. Also suppose every non-trivial element  centralizer of $G$ is abelian.
I need a counterexample with the following property:

1. $|G:Z(G)|=p^5$ (or respectively $p^7$).
2. $G$ contains a maximal non-abelian subgroup $M$, such that for every element in $g \in M \setminus Z(G)$, we have $C_G(g)\subseteq M$ and $|C_G(g):Z(G)|=p^2$ (respectively $p^3$).
3. For every element $h\in G\setminus M$, we have $|C_H(h):Z(H)|=p$.

P.S. If we omit the assumption every non-trivial centralizer is abelian, then with the help of partition of vector spaces such an example exist. A hyperspace and lines out of it.

Comment: What does "every non-trivial element centralizer of $G$ is abelian'' mean? The centralizer of a non-trivial element from $Z(G)$ is $G$, so $G$ were abelian.